# How to get php mail function to work on Debian “squeeze”?

Tags: linux, php, debian, smtp, php5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting PHP mail() function to work on Debian Lenny](https://serverfault.com/questions/47104/getting-php-mail-function-to-work-on-debian-lenny)

I have installed Apache and PHP5 on my debian server.

Firstly I tried it using sendmail. Here is the step by step procedure that I have tried :

```
Step 1: apt-get install sendmail
Step 2: /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

But this didn't work.

Then I tried using external SMTP .
My domain is registered on [BigRock](http://bigrock.com).I registerd an email address there `notifications@fostergen.com` and it gave me the required credentials.

On server I installed sSMTP

```
> apt-get install ssmtp
> Configured "/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf" file.
```

In the configuration file I added

```
root=notifications@fostergen.com
mailhub=smtp.fostergen.com:587 (Here I have doubt. I am not sure what to use here. I tried smtp.fostergen.com:587, smtp.fostergen.com:25,mx1.mailhostbox.com :587,mx1.mailhostbox.com:25.
```

I am still not sure what to use here mailhostbox.com. I used mx1.mailhostbox.com as it was the mx entry for my domain on bigrock Here is the screenshot![screenshot of bigrock's email management tool] )

`hostname=vs3204.ams2.alvotec.de` (I entered the command `hostname -f` on my server and got it as result )

```
FromLineOverride=YES    
UseSTARTTLS=YES    
AuthUser=notifications@fostergen.com    
AuthPass=password provided during email registration on bigrock

> edited /etc/ssmtp/revaliases 
(added " root:notifications@fostergen.com:mx1.mailhostbox.com :587 " in the last line)
> edited php.ini file (sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t)
> /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

But this didn't work.

After this I tried   eSMTP. Steps Performed :

```
> apt-get install esmtp
> edited /etc/esmtprc
    hostname=smtp.fostergen.com:587
   username= notifications@fostergen.com
   password: password provide by bigrock
    mda="/usr/bin/procmail -d %T"
> linked eSMTP to the legacy Sendmail path by execting the command "ln -s /usr/bin/esmtp /usr/bin/sendmail" 
> edited php.ini file (/usr/bin/sendmail -t -i)
> /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

But this technique also failed.

I just want to send email to users through php mail function. Kindly help. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Contact your hosting support, tell them the PHP mail function does not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

It look like your question is :"How do I install an mta on my dedicated server and use it with php5"?

Therefore, there are 2 step to follow :

- First one is to install an MTA. If you don't know much about mail servers, I suggest you postfix instead of sendmail: It is easier. For security reasons, **make sure it listens only on 127.0.0.1** as you don't want to receive/relay mail (inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1 in /etc/postfix/main.cf). Test that it works by sending an email from the command line interface. If it does not, look at logs (/var/log/mail.*).
- Second step is to configure php to use postfix. If I record correctly, default debian values work out of the box, so no change needed.

Comment: Thanks..I have solved this problem by using google's SMTP server instead of installing my own mail server :)